# Exclude overlay graphics from beamer handout

Tags: beamer, handout

I have some slides with overlays that contain an evolving picture:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics<1>{stage1.png}
    \includegraphics<2>{stage12.png}
    \includegraphics<3>{stage123.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

By default, all graphics are included in the handout. But I really only want to see the last one, which includes all information contained in the others. Also having all graphics at the same time destroys the layout.

Is there a command to achieve this, i.e. to eliminate parts of slides from the handout? Or can I include the graphics differently?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use `<x|handout:0>` in the spec:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \includegraphics<1|handout:0>{stage1.png}
    \includegraphics<2|handout:0>{stage12.png}
    \includegraphics<3>{stage123.png}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

See section 9.6.2 of `beameruserguide.pdf`, "Mode Specifications".